# Unable To Run File (Using Process)

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I have a button that runs an exe file, Code I'm using;

```
Process^ runFile = gcnew Process();
runFile->StartInfo->FileName = "C:\\Folder\\File.exe";
runFile->Start();
```

This works on my own PC, but if I run it on another one then it gives me an **Unhandled Exception** error.

The folder location + file are exactly the same on the other PC as they are on mine.

Any ideas on how this can be amended to work properly?

Edit - I have visual C++ on another laptop and have copied the project onto that and built it. After doing that, I can then run the application directly from the debug or release folder and it works.

My problem is that I want to be able to run this application from the release folder on PC's that won't have Visual C++ installed

Another quick edit - I tried using

```
System::Diagnostics::Process::Start
```

as well, but still no joy - I'm assuming this is an issue with me over the software... the CreateProcess function is working on other PC's when I'm pointing to applications like Chrome and then adding arguments for the website, but it's just not working when I want to run files from particular directories

=(

Comment: The most obvious failure mode here is that you simply did not deploy File.exe correctly.  You probably forgot to also copy its dependent DLLs.  The C runtime being the most typical oversight.  Or deploying the Debug build instead of the Release build.  Works on the other machine because the VS installer provided those DLLs.

Comment: If you're getting an unhandled exception error, handle the exception and tell us what it is. Enclosing the entire thing in `try { ... } catch (Exception^ e) { Debug::WriteLine(e); }` will do the trick.

Comment: On the PC where you're getting the unhandled exception, can you run `C:\Folder\File.exe` normally, e.g., by clicking it in Windows Explorer?

Comment: @DavidYaw Thank you for replying David. Yes I am able to run the file normally. The particular Exe's I'm trying to run from the button are simple netlogon scripts, mp4 videos, registry files etc.